# How can I submit a form to a new tab in my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Google chrome extension. the idea is that I enter my username and password, click submit and have a new tab open with my website, which will then pick up the submitted form and log me in.

I have managed to open my website in a new tab, but can not get it to pick up the form.

Comment: I don't understand where do you enter your username and password. On some page created by extension (popup page, options page etc.)? Data from this form should be then used to fill a form on another website and log you in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnClick event in submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="this.form.target='_blank';return true;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an HTML form in your popup.html as follows:

```
<form name="input" action="http://example.com/login.php" method="get">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

And in the script of your website you can check if the parameters and have been passed, and if correct then create redirect them to the DashBoard on your site, otherwise show them the login page to enter the correct credentials

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got your website loaded, try using jquery to select the textbox and enter a value.

The following selects the  where the input is, then finds the input I want, then finally sets the value inside of that box.

```
$("td[data-key='sku']").find("input.tb-input").val('some text here')
```

In the jquery code above, the html would look something like this:

```
<td data-key='sku'>
<input class=tb-input/>
</td>
```